# Prevent Django from creating tables -connecting to existing DB

Tags: django

I am developing an application in Django for my company. Planning to use an existing DB. When I was playing around Django, I saw the framework creating django_sessions table when the server fired up, and other tables when migrate command is provided. Since I am planning to use existing DB, how can I prevent Django from creating Django_session. Other tables, as I understand, are created only when migrate b is fired.

django 1.8.6 and python 2.7.11

Completely new to Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two options here.

- don't run `python manage.py migrate`, which means only install apps for which no tables are required. this makes `migrate` obsolete. but than you will miss a few features, e.g. sessions.
- provide a separate database for django related data. therefor django provides [multiple database support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#defining-your-databases) and [model meta options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#managed) which allows you to define on model level how and if django should deal with the database schema.

Depending on what features you expect and need you should pick one of those setups.

Comment: thanks dahrens, what idid was, provided seperate DB. named the inbuilt sqlite DB  as 'default' and the other on as 'appDB', in this way, only default db had the tables

Comment: also, can the django related DB be simple db like sqlite ?

Comment: as long as you don't need to scale and the performance is enough i don't see a problem there. if you encounter high load you should switch to a real DB.